Как сделать отложенную загрузку фрейма в MODX?
Фрейм добавляется в текстовом редакторе через ТВ. Хотел сделать отложенную загрузку что бы ускорить загрузку страницы. Но при добавлении фрейма в редактор из него удаляется атрибут loading и остается только сам фрейм. Где-то прочел что это делается для безопасности. Можно ли как то это обойти? В итоге должно получиться так
<iframe loading="lazy" src="https://youtube.com/embed/hm-VkhG7j7h" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>


Попробуйте отложить загрузку iframe через таймаут, прописав например так:
function loadIFrame() {
    window.frames['YourFrame'].document.location.href = "https://youtube.com/embed/hm-VkhG7j7h";
}         
function delayedLoad() {
    window.setTimeout(loadIFrame, 3000);
}

А сам iframe будет выглядеть так:
<iframe src="" onLoad="delayedLoad()"></iframe>

Если редактор что-то "съедает", можно код разместить в теле шаблона.

Я тоже думал об этом. Но код фрейма должен загружаться из админки.

А какой тип поля был? если WYSIWYG редактор, может заменить на простое, текстовое? Ну или "научить" редактор ничего не вырезать..

да, это WYSIWYG. а как его научить? я где то прочитал что modx режет все лишнее в целях безопасности.

Какой редактор используется?

Пардон, там не WYSIWYG а Rich Text

ну так это вроде как одно и то же)) название редактора подскажите

не понял. о каком еще названии речь?

у вас когда поле с типом richtext, если не отключен и используется, должен вызываться визуальный редактор, так вот какой он? Скриншота будет достаточно. Ну или подскажите значения системных переменных use_editor и which_editor

http://linkme.ufanet.ru/images/41167989cb75f0cd1539eb3db359b67e.png
